# "Argument expression is not valid" error with EF4 Linq sub select query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, exception, telerik-open-access

Any ideas as to why this query compiles, but then throws this runtime error:

> Argument expression is not valid

I know I could change my db model, but in this case it's not possible.
Any ideas how to get something like this working? Not even sure what this would be called. Thanks.

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();
var books = (from b in db.BOOKS
             select new
             {
                 b.ID,
                 b.NAME,
                 AuthorName = db.PEOPLEs.Where(p=>p.ID==b.AUTHOR).First().USER_ID,
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: DbContext is entity framework 4, not LinqToSql.

Comment: What does the table look like?

Comment: I went ahead and updated the title to accurately reflect the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found I have the best luck with complex inner queries by using let expressions.  This does a subselect and allows you greater flexibility to bind an element from a subselect.  HOWEVER, notice that I am only doing a First() on the author assignment in the anonymous object.  This is because if you do a First().PropertyName and First yields a null value it will blow up.

Good luck and double check syntax.  I don't have your full object set so I cannot generate a fully working demo, however, this was tested with an object tree that I have on one of my own projects.

```
var books = (
        from b in db.BOOKs
        let author = (from a in db.PEOPLEs
                      where b.AUTHOR == a.ID
                      select a)
        select new
        {
            ID = b.ID,
            NAME = b.Name,
            Author = author.First()
        }
    ).ToList();    

foreach(var x in books)
{
    string AuthorName = x.Author.USER_ID;
    //Do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, `First<T>()` also have an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) `First<T>(Predicate<T>)`, i.e.:

```
AuthorName = db.PEOPLEs.First(p=>p.ID==b.AUTHOR).USER_ID
```

---

You can use LINQ in methods styles:

```
var books = (from b in db.BOOKS
             let author = db.PEOPLEs.Where(p => p.ID == b.AUTHOR).First()
             select new
             {
                 b.ID,
                 b.NAME,
                 AuthorName = author.USER_ID,
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: What an elaborate use of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look on your code, you have

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();
var books = (from b in db.BOOKS
select new
{
    b.ID,
    b.NAME,
    AuthorName = db.PEOPLEs.Where(p=>p.ID==b.AUTHOR).First().USER_ID, <<-- Here coma
}).ToList();
```

It is expecting another parameter there, just remove it and it sould pass

:)

Comment: added formatting to this post, code block was not all marked as code.

Comment: actually linq doesn't care about the ending comma. similar to an array expression.

Answer (score 0):

So, the final solution was:

```
var books = (
    from b in db.BOOKs
    let author = (from a in db.PEOPLEs
                    where b.AUTHOR == a.ID
                    select a)
    select new
    {
        ID = b.ID,
        NAME = b.Name,
        Author = author.First().USER_ID
    }
).ToList();
```

Thanks!